# Solr-Zookeeper increment the number of shards without setting max number of shards

Tags: solr, sharding, apache-zookeeper

I have a problem in creating shards with zoo keeper.

When I create a collection and the shards for the corresponding collection ,I have to specify max number of shards the collection going to have.If I started any new solr server it will be considered as new shard by zoo keeper.This will happen up to maximum number of shards I specified during the collection creation.

What is my requirement is,without specifying maximum number of shards, I have to make zoo keeper to consider the newly started solr instance as shards for the corresponding collection.

How to achieve this functionality .....?